# LISP, global variable is being modified

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

im working on a program in lisp that uses this list to inform the user of which plants cures which viruses or have special properties.

```
PARAMETER PLANTS ((NAME...)(VIREN...)(EIGENSCHAFTEN...)(VERRINGERN ...)(VERBESSERN ...))
(DEFPARAMETER PLANTS 
'(
 ((NAME TRAGANT ASTRALAGUS)(VIREN INFLUENZA ADENOVIREN HERPES-SIMPLEX COXSACKIE-VIRUS INFEKTIOESE-BURSITIS-DER-HUEHNER CYTOMEGALOVIRUS PUNTA-TORO-VIREN JAPANISCHE-ENZEPHALITIS PORCINE-PARVOVIRUS HEPATITIS-B STAUPE BUNYAVIREN)(EIGENSCHAFTEN ADAPTOGEN ANTIBAKTERIELL ANTIHEPATOTOXISCH ANTIVIRAL KARDIOPROTEKTIV DIURETIKUM BLUTDRUCKSENKEND IMMUNSTAERKER )(VERBESSERN BLUTKREISLAUF IMMUNFUNKTION)(VERRINGERN VIRALEN-INFEKTIONEN))
 ((NAME CORDYCEPS CORDYCEPS)(VIREN INFLUENZA HERPES-SIMPLEX HIV HEPATITIS-B NEWCASTLE-INFEKTION TUBERKELBAZILLUS PLASMODIUM CLOSTRIDIEN STAPHYLOCOCCUS-AUREUS ENTEROCOCCUS-FAECALIS BACILLUS-SUBTILIS CANDIDA-ALBICANS KREBS)(EIGENSCHAFTEN ANTIVIRAL ANTIASTHMATISCH ANTIBAKTERIELL ANTIKONVULSIVUM ENTZUENDUNGSHEMMEND ANTIMIKROBIELL ANTIOXIDATIONS FIEBERSENKEND ANTITUMORMITTEL ANTITUSSIVUM BRONCHIALREGULATOR KARDIOTONISCH SCHLEIMLOESEND HEPATOPROTEKTIV HYPOGLYKAEMISCH HYPOLIPIDAEMISCH IMMUNMODULATOR INSEKTIZID MITOCHONDRIEN-ADAPTOGEN NERVENBERUHIGUNG NEUROPROTEKTIV NIERENSCHUETZEND SCHLAFREGULIEREND STEROIDBILDEND)(VERRINGERN KONVULSIONEN ASTHMA VIRALEN-INFEKTIONEN ENTZUENDUNGEN FATIGUE HUSTEN SCHWINDELGEFUEHLE NYKTURIE)(VERBESSERN LIBIDO))
 ((NAME BAIKAL-HELMKRAUT SCUTELLARIA-BAICALENSIS)(VIREN INFLUENZA ADENOVIREN INFEKTIOESE-BRONCHITIS ENTEROBAKTERIOPHAGE-MS2 COXSACKIE-VIRUS EPSTEIN-BARR-VIREN HEPATITIS-A HEPATITIS-B HEPATITIS-C HERPES-SIMPLEX HIV LEUKAEMIE MASERN MOSAIKVIRUS PARAINFLUENZA POLIOVIRUS PRRS-VIREN HRSV SARS-COV SENDAIVIRUS-INFEKTION STOMATITIS-VESICULARIS )(EIGENSCHAFTEN ANODYNE ANTIANAPHYLAKTISCH ANTIANGIOGENE ANTIBAKTERIELL ANTIVIRAL ANTICHOLESTEROLEMIKUM ANTIKONVULSIVUM ANTIDIARRHOISCH ANTIDYSENTERISCH ANTIMYKOTISCH ANTIHYPERTENSIV ENTZUENDUNGSHEMMEND ANTIMETASTISCH ANTIOXIDATIONS ANTISPASMODISCH ANTITUMORMITTEL ADSTRINGIEREND CHOLAGOGUM DIURETIKUM SCHLEIMLOESEND FIEBERSENKEND BLUTSTILLEND HEPATOPROTEKTIV SEDATIVUM NERVENSTAERKEND NEUROPROTEKTIV)(VERBESSERN GEHIRNFUNKTION)(VERRINGERN VIRALEN-INFEKTIONEN FIEBER DURCHFALL DYSENTERIE REIZ KRAMPFANFALL KONVULSIONEN INSOMNIE))
 ((NAME HOLUNDER SAMBUCUS)(VIREN HERPES-SIMPLEX COXSACKIE-VIRUS ENTEROVIREN HIV INFLUENZA CHIKUNGUNYAFIEBER EPSTEIN-BARR-VIREN HEPATITIS-B HEPATITIS-C HEPATITIS-E JAPANISCHE-ENZEPHALITIS WEST-NILE-ENZEPHALITIS STOMATITIS-VESICULARIS POLIOVIRUS ADENOVIREN PORCINE-CIRCOVIRUS PORCINE-EPIDEMIC-DIARRHEA-VIRUS RHINOVIRENES JUNIN-VIRUS CYTOMEGALOVIRUS HRSV TABAKMOSAIKVIRUS SARS-COV DENGUE VOGELPOCKEN ROTAVIRUS STAUPE MURINE-NOROVIRUS FELINE-CALICIVIRUS EBOLAFIEBER )(EIGENSCHAFTEN ANTIVIRAL ANTIBAKTERIELL ANTIMYKOTISCH ANALGETISCH ENTZUENDUNGSHEMMEND ANTINOZIZEPTIV KREBSHEMMEND ANTIANGIOGEN ANTITERATOGEN SCHWEISSTREIBEND DIURETIKUM PROSTAGLANDIN-SYNTHESE-HEMMEND FIEBERSENKEND ANTIOXIDATIONS IMMUNSTIMULIEREND)(VERRINGERN FIEBER SCHMERZ ENTZUENDUNGEN SCHWELLUNGEN VIRALEN-INFEKTIONEN)(VERBESSERN SCHWITZEN IMMUNFUNKTION ERBRECHEN LEBERSCHUTZ))
 ((NAME INGWER ZINGIBER-OFFICINALE)(VIREN ERKAELTUNG INFLUENZA HEPATITIS HERPES-SIMPLEX GELBFIEBER MASERN WINDPOCKEN ENTEROVIREN RHINOVIREN CYTOMEGALOVIRUS HEPATITIS-C HIV EPSTEIN-BARR-VIREN NEWCASTLE-INFEKTION VACCINIAVIRUS MOSAIKVIRUS POLIOVIRUS)(EIGENSCHAFTEN ANTIVIRAL ANALGETIKUM ANTHELMINTHIKUM ANTIARTHRITISCH ANTIBAKTERIELL ANTIDIARRHOISCH ANTIEMETIKUM ANTIMYKOTISCH ENTZUENDUNGSHEMMEND KRAMPFLOESEND ANTITUSSIVUM KARMINATIVUM KREISLAUFSTIMULANS SCHWEISSTREIBEND ELASTASE-HEMMER BLUTDRUCKSENKEND IMMUNSTAERKER SYNERGIST)(VERBESSERN SCHWITZEN IMMUNFUNKTION BLUTKREISLAUF)(VERRINGERN VIRALEN-INFEKTIONEN NASENSCHLEIMHAUT DURCHFALL MOMADE KRAMPFANFALL FIEBER SCHUETTELFROS ENTZUENDUNGEN HUSTEN ANGSTZUSTAENDE SCHMERZ ERKAELTUNG MIGRAENE KOPFSCHMERZEN))
 ((NAME HOUTTUYNIA HOUTTUYNIA-CORDATA)(VIREN INFLUENZA SARS-COV DENGUE SEROTYPE-2 INFEKTIOESE-BRONCHITIS ENTEROVIREN ENTERIC-CYTOPATHIC-HUMAN-ORPHAN HERPES-SIMPLEX HIV CYTOMEGALOVIRUS PED-VIRUS HERPES-SIMPLEX)(EIGENSCHAFTEN ANTIVIRAL ANALGETIKUM ANTHELMINTHIKUM ANTIBAKTERIELL ANTIKREBS ANTIMYKOTISCH ENTZUENDUNGSHEMMEND ANTILEUKAEMISCH ANTIMIKROBIELL ANTIOXIDATIONS ANTITUSSIVUM ADSTRINGIEREND DIURETIKUM ENTSCHLACKEND EMMENAGOGUM FEBRIFUGE BLUTSTILLEND HYPOGLYKAEMISCH IMMUNMODULATORISCH LARVAZIDUM ABFUEHRMITTEL AUGENHEILKUNDE)(VERRINGERN VIRALEN-INFEKTIONEN HARNWEGE-INFEKTIONEN NIEREN-INFEKTIONEN GENITALBEREICH-INFEKTIONEN DYSENTERIE DURCHFALL AUGES-INFEKTIONEN HAUT-INFEKTIONEN))
 ((NAME WAID ISATIS)(VIREN INFLUENZA SARS-COV COXSACKIE-VIRUS ROETELN LEUKAEMIE INFEKTIOESE-BRONCHITIS HRSV ADENOVIREN MASERN MUMPS WINDPOCKEN EPSTEIN-BARR-VIREN HEPATITIS-B HERPES-SIMPLEX CYTOMEGALOVIRUS HFRS PRRS-VIREN PSEUDOWUT NEWCASTLE-INFEKTION GUERTELROSE)(EIGENSCHAFTEN ANTIVIRAL ANTIENTZUENDLICH FIEBERSENKEND ANTINOZIZEPTIV ANTIALLERGISCH TYROSINASE-HEMMER ANTIOXIDATIONS ANTIMYKOTISCH ANTIBAKTERIELL ANTIPARASITAER ANTILEUKAEMISCH ANTITUMOR UREASE-HEMMER SERIN-PROTEASE-HEMMSTOFF HEMMSTOFF-DER-BUTYRYCHOLINESTERASE LIPOXYGENASE-HEMMER ANTIENDOTOXIN DIOXIN-ANTAGONIST)(VERRINGERN VIRALEN-INFEKTIONEN)(VERBESSERN BLUTKREISLAUF))
 ((NAME ECHTES-SUESSHOLZ GLYCYRRHIZA-GLABRA)(VIREN INFLUENZA SARS-COV HRSV PARAINFLUENZA JAPANISCHE-ENZEPHALITIS TICK-BORNE-ENCEPHALITIS WEST-NILE-ENZEPHALITIS GELBFIEBER DENGUE PNEUMONIE INFEKTIOESE-BRONCHITIS ENTEROVIREN ROTAVIRUS ADENOVIREN COXSACKIE-VIRUS NEWCASTLE-INFEKTION VACCINIAVIRUS STOMATITIS-VESICULARIS HIV CYTOMEGALOVIRUS HERPES-SIMPLEX HEPATITIS-A HEPATITIS-B HEPATITIS-C HEPATITIS-D HEPATITIS-E WINDPOCKEN EPSTEIN-BARR-VIREN POLIOVIRUS MASERN CHANDIPURA PSEUDORABIES VOVINE-IMMUNODEFICIENCY MURINE-RETROVIRUS PRRS-VIREN )(EIGENSCHAFTEN ANTIVIRAL NEBENNIERENRINDE-STIMULANS NEBENNIERE-TONIK SCHMERZSTILLEND ANTIBAKTERIELL KREBSHEMMEND ANTITUMORMITTEL ANTIHAEMOLYTISCH ANTIHYPERGLYKAEMISCH ENTZUENDUNGSHEMMEND ANTIOXIDATIONS KRAMPFLOESEND ANTISTRESSIVUM ANTITUSSIVUM GEGEN-MAGENGESCHWUERE KARDIOPROTEKTIV ABFUEHRMITTEL OESTROGENE SCHLEIMLOESEND HEMMSTOFF-DER-MAGENSEKRETION HEPATOPROTEKTIV IMMUNSTIMULIEREND ABFUEHRMITTEL SCHLEIMHAUTSCHUETZEND STRAHLENSCHUTZ MUSKELENTSPANNER STIMULANS-BAUCHSPEICHELDRUESE SYNERGIST STIMULANS-THYMUSDRUESE TYROSINASE-HEMMER XANTHIN-OXIDASE-HEMMER)(VERRINGERN SCHMERZ MUND-BAKTERIELLEN-INFEKTIONEN VIRALEN-INFEKTIONEN KRAMPFANFALL GESCHWUERBILDUNG)(VERBESSERN IMMUNFUNKTION))
 ((NAME LOMATIUM LOMATIUM)(VIREN INFLUENZA SARS-COV VIRAL-ENCEPHALITIS PNEUMONIE EPSTEIN-BARR CYTOMEGALOVIRUS HIV SHIGELLA BAKTERIELLE-INFEKTIONEN)(EIGENSCHAFTEN SCHMERZSTILLEND ANTIBAKTERIELL ANTIMYKOTISCH ANTIMIKROBIELL ANTISEPTISCH KRAMPFLOESEND ANTIVIRAL SCHLEIMLOESEND SCHLEIMHAUT-TONIK)(VERRINGERN KRAMPFANFALL SCHMERZ VIRALEN-INFEKTIONEN BAKTERIELLEN-INFEKTIONEN))
 ((NAME DURCHWACHSENER-WASSERDOST EUPATORIUM-PERFOLIATUM)(VIREN INFLUENZA MALARIA DENGUE)(EIGENSCHAFTEN SCHMERZSTILLEND ANTIBAKTERIELL ENTZUENDUNGSHEMMEND ZYTOTOXISCH SCHWEISSTREIBEND BRECHMITTEL FIEBERSENKEND BITTER-DEN-MAGEN IMMUNSTIMULIEREND SCHLEIMHAUT-TONIK BLUTSTILLEND GLATTER-MUSKEL-ENTSPANNEND)(VERRINGERN VIRALEN-INFEKTIONEN FIEBER SCHMERZ)(VERBESSERN SCHLEIMHAUT BLUTKREISLAUF SCHWITZEN))
 ((NAME AMERIKANISCHE-SAECKELBLUME CEANOTHUS-AMERICANUS)(VIREN INFLUENZA)(EIGENSCHAFTEN LYMPHSYSTEMS-STIMULANS LYMPHSYSTEM-TONIK BLUTGERINNUNGSMITTEL)(VERRINGERN ENTZUENDUNGEN)(VERBESSERN LYMPHSYSTEMS BLUTKREISLAUF))
 ((NAME ROSENWURZ RHODIOLA-ROSEA)(VIREN INFLUENZA HEPATITIS-C COXSACKIE-VIRUS JAPANISCHE-ENZEPHALITIS ENTEROVIREN STAPHYLOCOCCUS-AUREUS BACILLUS-SUBTILIS TUBERKELBAZILLUS E-COLI)(EIGENSCHAFTEN ADAPTOGEN NEBENNIEREPROTEKTIV ANTI-KREBS ANTIDEPRESSIVUM GEGEN-MUEDIGKEIT ANTIOXIDATIONS ANTISTRESSIVUM KARDIOTONISCH ENDOKRINES-TONIK ERGOGEN HIPPOCAMPUS-SCHUTZMITTEL HIPPOCAMPUS-TONIK HYPOXIE-ANTAGONIST IMMUNSTAERKER MITOCHONDRIEN-STAERKEN MUSKELN-STIMULANS NERVENSYSTEMS-TONIK NERVENPROTEKTIV SYNERGIST)(VERRINGERN STRESS DEPRESSION FATIGUE ERSCHOEPFUNG GEHIRNNEBEL)(VERBESSERN MITOCHONDRIEN MUSKELN NERVENSYSTEMS ENDOKRINES IMMUNFUNKTION))
 ))
```

one of the functions that i have is printall that show the users all the viruses/properties/benefits... that are currently available in the database.

it works but the problem is after running the program my global variable PLANTS is somehow edited, creating duplicates.

```
;FUNCTION SORTER 
;ORDER A LIST IN ALPHATHIC ORDER
;@PARAM RECORD: {LIST}, LIST THAT WILL BE WORKED
;RETURNS: {LIST}; ORDERED LIST
(DEFUN SORTER(RECORD)
    (SORT RECORD #'STRING<=) 
)

;FUNCTION PRINTALL 
;SEARCHES THE GIVEN TYPE IN THE LIST PRINTS ALL AVAILABLE OPTIONS
;@PARAM TYPE: {STRING}, NAME OF THE TYPE ('NAME, 'VIREN, 'EIGENSCHAFTEN OR 'ZIEL).
;@PARAM LIS: {LIST}, LIST WITH ALL INFORMATION ABOUT THE PLANTS, VIRUSES, PROPERTIES AND TREATMENT TARGETS.
;@PARAM RESULT: {LIST}, LIST OF ALL POSSIBLE OPTIONS BASED ON TYPE.
;@PARAM RESULT2: {LIST}, LIST OF ALL 'IMPROVE TARGETS
;@RETURNS () NIL.
(DEFUN PRINTALL(TYPE LIS &OPTIONAL RESULT RESULT2) 
    (COND((AND (NULL LIS)(EQL TYPE 'ZIELE))(FORMAT T "~%THE AVAILABLE THERAPY GOALS ARE:~%~%1: REDUCING ~{~a~^, ~}.~%~%2: IMPROVING ~{~a~^, ~}.~%" (SORTER(REMOVE-DUPLICATES RESULT))(SORTER(REMOVE-DUPLICATES RESULT2))))
        ((AND (NULL LIS)(EQL TYPE 'NAME))(FORMAT T "~%~A~%" RESULT ))
        ((NULL LIS)(FORMAT T "~%ALL AVAILABLE ~a:~%~{~a~^, ~}.~%" TYPE (SORTER(REMOVE-DUPLICATES RESULT))))
        ((EQL TYPE 'NAME )(PRINTALL TYPE (CDR LIS)(NCONC RESULT (LIST(CDR (ASSOC TYPE (CAR LIS)))))))
       ((EQL TYPE 'ZIELE)(PRINTALL TYPE (CDR LIS)(NCONC RESULT (CDR (ASSOC 'VERRINGERN (CAR LIS))))(NCONC RESULT2 (CDR (ASSOC 'VERBESSERN (CAR LIS))))))    
        (T (PRINTALL TYPE (CDR LIS)(NCONC RESULT (CDR (ASSOC TYPE (CAR LIS))))))
))
```

Example: (PRINTALL 'EIGENSCHAFTEN PLANTS );-->

```
ALL AVAILABLE VIREN:
ADENOVIREN, BACILLUS-SUBTILIS, BAKTERIELLE-INFEKTIONEN, BUNYAVIREN, CANDIDA-ALBICANS, CHANDIPURA, CHIKUNGUNYAFIEBER, CLOSTRIDIEN, COXSACKIE-VIRUS, CYTOMEGALOVIRUS, DENGUE, E-COLI, EBOLAFIEBER, ENTERIC-CYTOPATHIC-HUMAN-ORPHAN, ENTEROBAKTERIOPHAGE-MS2, ENTEROCOCCUS-FAECALIS, ENTEROVIREN, EPSTEIN-BARR, EPSTEIN-BARR-VIREN, ERKAELTUNG, FELINE-CALICIVIRUS, GELBFIEBER, GUERTELROSE, HEPATITIS, HEPATITIS-A, HEPATITIS-B, HEPATITIS-C, HEPATITIS-D, HEPATITIS-E, HERPES-SIMPLEX, HFRS, HIV, HRSV, INFEKTIOESE-BRONCHITIS, INFEKTIOESE-BURSITIS-DER-HUEHNER, INFLUENZA, JAPANISCHE-ENZEPHALITIS, JUNIN-VIRUS, KREBS, LEUKAEMIE, MALARIA, MASERN, MOSAIKVIRUS, MUMPS, MURINE-NOROVIRUS, MURINE-RETROVIRUS, NEWCASTLE-INFEKTION, PARAINFLUENZA, PED-VIRUS, PLASMODIUM, PNEUMONIE, POLIOVIRUS, PORCINE-CIRCOVIRUS, PORCINE-EPIDEMIC-DIARRHEA-VIRUS, PORCINE-PARVOVIRUS, PRRS-VIREN, PSEUDORABIES, PSEUDOWUT, PUNTA-TORO-VIREN, RHINOVIREN, RHINOVIRENES, ROETELN, ROTAVIRUS, SARS-COV, SENDAIVIRUS-INFEKTION, SEROTYPE-2, SHIGELLA, STAPHYLOCOCCUS-AUREUS, STAUPE, STOMATITIS-VESICULARIS, TABAKMOSAIKVIRUS, TICK-BORNE-ENCEPHALITIS, TUBERKELBAZILLUS, VACCINIAVIRUS, VIRAL-ENCEPHALITIS, VOGELPOCKEN, VOVINE-IMMUNODEFICIENCY, WEST-NILE-ENZEPHALITIS, WINDPOCKEN.
```

running printall on the same type a second time return this error:  Circular list given to NCONC.

can someone please let me know how/where am i editing the global variable?
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some Common Lisp functions are destructive- they don't return a copy of their argument, but modify the original value. [`nconc`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_nconc.htm) and [`sort`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_sort_.htm) are destructive.

Some other notes about your code:

- You can (and should) write your code in lowercase.
- You are sometimes missing spaces.
- Ending parentheses belong to the same line.

So, this function:

```
(DEFUN SORTER(RECORD)
    (SORT RECORD #'STRING<=) 
)
```

should look like this:

```
(defun sorter (record)
  (sort record #'string<=))
```

I don't understand why you're using recursion to iterate over `plants`- you can use [`mapcar`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm) and get the desired result in one step. I tried to simplify your function- maybe it doesn't cover all functionality, but you will get some general idea:

```
(defun printall (type data)
  (format t "~%ALL AVAILABLE ~a:~%~{~a~^, ~}.~%" type
          (sort (remove-duplicates 
                 (apply #'append 
                        (mapcar (lambda (row) (cdr (assoc type row))) data))) 
                #'string<=)))
```

Test:

```
(printall 'NAME PLANTS)
(printall 'VIREN PLANTS)
```

Comment: maybe use MAPCAN ?

Comment: @RainerJoswig: `mapcan` uses `nconc` internally- I'm not sure if it wouldn't cause some similar errors.

Comment: One could use COPY-LIST inside the LAMBDA, that way one avoids the CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT of APPLY.

Comment: thank you for the notes and the information about the destructive lisp functions